# Freeing a global variable in delphi

Tags: delphi

I am aware that it is not wise to use global variables indiscriminately.  However, I needed to use one - a TStringList.  My question is how (and where) do I free it?  Searched, but could not find any documentation on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Free it when you are done with it. Perhaps in a finalization block. Only you know the required lifetime. My top tip is to make sure you don't free before you've finished using it. Of course, another solution might be not use a global at all.

Comment: I tried the following code, but it gave me errors at the ; for the end in the finalization section: `implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  AnalysisOptions;

var
  OutputFile: TStringList;

initialization
  OutputFile := TStringList.Create;
finalization
  OutPutFile.Free;
end;



procedure EstimateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

//
OutputFile.Add(...)

end;

...

procedure SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

OutputFile.Save(...);

end;`

Comment: Call me a heretic, but when you only free it in finalization you might as well leave it open, because the program shutdown will free all resources regardless.  _(Yes FastMM4 will report it as a leak if you ask it too, but it's really not, it's just Windows cleaning it up slightly later or you cleaning it up slightly earlier)_.  If you can do it earlier, **then** cleaning up is useful.

Comment: @Johan, [`I'm a pedant`](http://i.imgur.com/u5JPpbA.jpg) even though you're right :-)

Comment: @Johan: if you are going to leak the object at shutdown, then register the object with FastMM so it does not get reported as a leak.

Comment: @user1505202: `initialization` and `finalization` sections need to be at the end of the unit: `unit MyUnit;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  AnalysisOptions;

var
  OutputFile: TStringList;

procedure EstimateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // OutputFile.Add(...)
end;

...

procedure SaveClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OutputFile.Save(...);
end;

initialization
  OutputFile := TStringList.Create;

finalization
  OutPutFile.Free;

end.`

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but I think we'd have better suggestions if you showed some code.

Comment: @Remy: if you want to take the trouble of registering it with FastMM, you can just as well free it in the finalization section, which is, IMO, still the better way. I know the OS will clean it up anyway, but somehow that doesn't feel right.

Comment: @Rudy: understood and agreed. But there are also legitimate reasons to register known memory leaks, otherwise FastMM would not expose registration functions for it. In Indy, we did encounter issues with freeing some of its globals in finalization sections, so Indy has a compiler define to control whether to free them or let them leak and register them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be answered by keeping in mind the basic principle of memory management: [the Single Ownership Principle](http://tech.turbu-rpg.com/106/delphi-memory-management-made-simple).  Every variable should have one single owner whose responsibility it is to clean it up.

Whatever code creates your `TStringList` should also be responsible for destroying it (and, if it's a global, setting the global variable to **nil**) at the appropriate time.  So where are you creating it?

When I have globals, generally representing important resources, they're usually set up by an object that manages the entire program.  They get created on initialization, and cleaned up during destruction of the main object.  On the other hand, if you're creating it in an `initialization` section of a unit, you'll want the cleanup to be in that same unit's `finalization` section.

Comment: I create it in a procedure called Estimate and can free it there, but it is possible that the user may want to save the contents of the TStringList.  Obviously, if I free it at the end of the procedure Estimate, the Save procedure (an OnClick procedure for the Save command in the File menu) cannot access the contents.  Yes, I can free it in the Save procedure.  But then, what if the user does not want to save the contents?  It will never be freed.

Comment: @user1505202: This looks like a scoping issue for you.  If it's part of some code that's attached to a form, why isn't this TStringList a member of the form object instead of being a global?

Comment: Perhaps I am using the wrong term when I say global.  I meant that I have declared the TStringList in the implementation section and then create it in a procedure called Estimate.  Another procedure called Save then accesses it to save it.  Where do I free it?

Comment: In that case, I'd probably free it in the `finalization` section of your unit.  But it's still probably worth looking at, to see if you can make it a member of the class, either as an instance member or as a class var.  (If you're on Delphi XE or later--or maybe D2010, not certain--you can set up and free class vars with class constructors and class destructors.)

Comment: Freeing it in the Finalization section worked.  Thanks.  I was having trouble placing these sections.  I need to acknowledge all of you - how do I do it?  Btw, one comment is missing - it was the clincher!

Comment: @user1505202: The usual way to acknowledge someone on here is to accept their answer (click the checkmark icon just below the voting widget for that answer).

Answer (score 2):

A TStringList should be safe to initialize in `initialization` and free in `finalization` sections.

As recommendation, consider encapsualting the access to the global variable into a function, this way you could move the var declaration into the `implementation` part and have more control over it.

Note that `initialization` and `finalization` may be inappropriate in other cases. Especially when threads are involved or `LoadLibrary() / FreeLibrary()` calls are required, it is better to have dedicated procedures to do that in the normal program flow. Both `initialization` and `finalization` sections are executed in a state, where Windows prevents certain things.

Comment: I have never used initialization and finalization sections in any program.  My research seems to suggest that these sections are outside of any procedure.  So if I create the TStringList in the Initialization section, I free it in the Finalization section?  Here is my code.   `implementation
 {$R *.dfm}
 uses
   AnalysisOptions;

 var
   OutputFile: TStringList;

 initialization
   OutputFile := TStringList.Create;
 finalization
   OutPutFile.Free;
 end;`




 procedure TfrmHillSlopeRegr.mmuFileOpenClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin

 //

 end;

Comment: The compiler did not like the ";" after the "end"

Comment: That worked!  I was trying to put it at the beginning.  Got it.  Thanks.

Comment: The initial answers by David Heffeman, Mason Wheeler and JensG) pointed me in the right direction (using initialization and finalization sections) and the comment by Lans (I think that was the name, but I can't find the comment anymore!) was the clincher.  I would like to acknowledge all of you for having helped, but not sure how.

Comment: It was me. But I deleted my comment when I realized that global variable is not the best for you. (there was included [`this hotfix`](http://pastebin.com/zHYGtCQh)) for the code from your comment. If you need to have your variable accessible just in scope of the form, then you want to have it declared as a private field (like shown in [`this example`](http://pastebin.com/snuG19te)) and create and destroy the object instance of that variable in the form's `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` event methods.

Comment: @TLama, thanks for surfacing!  Both your examples are very helpful. I used your first one but see that the second example is probably better. Don't know how to acknowledge you, though.